# ProgressBar not showing in layout

Tags: java, android, user-interface, progress-bar

I'm trying to implement a spinning `progressBar` but it won't show up no matter what I try. This is the xml:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/background"
tools:context="com.example.home.quoteapp.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:background="@color/background">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rectangle">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/search"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:gravity="center" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/back_arrow_search"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_black_24dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/nav_button"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_more_vert_black_24dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/section"
                android:layout_width="230dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/nav_button"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/nav_button"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:ems="10"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"
                android:maxHeight="140dp"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:text="@string/section"
                android:textColor="@color/textColor"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/searchText"
                android:layout_width="230dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/section"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/section"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/section"
                android:background="@drawable/underline"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Search"
                android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions|text"
                android:maxHeight="140dp"
                android:textColor="@color/textColor"
                android:textColorHint="@color/textHint"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:visibility="invisible" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/progressBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:alwaysDrawnWithCache="true"
        android:clipChildren="true"
        android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:scrollingCache="true"
        android:smoothScrollbar="true"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="5dp"></GridView>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navView"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@color/headerColour"
    android:theme="@style/NavigationTheme"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:itemBackground="@drawable/nav_item_background"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/headerColourAccent"
    app:menu="@menu/menu">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@color/headerColourAccent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            android:text="Sections"
            android:textColor="@color/headerColour"
            android:textSize="30dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And this is what I call in the `MainActivity` for the `progressBar`.

```
private RelativeLayout progressBarLayout;

private ProgressBar progressBar


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    progressBarLayout = findViewById(R.id.progressBarLayout);
    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    progressBar.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(0xF09D00, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
}
```

And then I would make the `progressBar` go away by doing this

```
progressBarLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

But the `progressBar` is never shown and when I set the visiblity to gone on the `progressBarLayout` it does go away.

Comment: Try to set exact width/height values for progressBar (not wrap_content, as it shown in your code)

Comment: Even when I set the width and height to 100dp or match_parent, it doesn't show

Comment: is there a specific reason why this progress bar is in the appbar layout? If not just put the progress bar and gridview after the </AppBarLayout> and you will see them

Comment: I tried that but it also didn't show up. https://hastebin.com/ozasizajih.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your layout hierarchy. I made some few changes.
The root is now a `RelativeLayout` containing the `DrawerLayout` and the `Progressbar` is removed outside the `DrawerLayout` and is now inside the root layout down below the `DrawerLayout`. Also the `AppBarLayout` was taking the whole screens width and height, which I guess isn't what you want, so that was changed to since it was blocking the other views below it

Here is a working layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!--Drawer related content below here-->

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="top">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/search"
                    android:layout_width="35dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:gravity="center" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/back_arrow_search"
                    android:layout_width="35dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/nav_button"
                    android:layout_width="35dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/section"
                    android:layout_width="230dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/nav_button"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/nav_button"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:inputType="textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"
                    android:maxHeight="140dp"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/searchText"
                    android:layout_width="230dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/section"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/section"
                    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/section"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="Search"
                    android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
                    android:inputType="textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions|text"
                    android:maxHeight="140dp"
                    android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/progressBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:alwaysDrawnWithCache="true"
            android:clipChildren="true"
            android:columnWidth="90dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:scrollingCache="true"
            android:smoothScrollbar="true"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:verticalSpacing="5dp" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navView"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:visibility="invisible">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:paddingTop="15dp"
                android:text="Sections"
                android:textSize="30dp" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

<ProgressBar
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:indeterminate="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for your time but it didn't work, it still doesn't show anything.

Comment: Did you try to put the entire XML code and run the app? because it works perfectly for me

Comment: Oh yeah it does work, but somehow the gridview doesn't show anymore, but I am able to click on the items in the gridview. It was this part     progressBar.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(0xF09D00, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY); that didn't make it show up when I used your xml file.

Comment: Beawre of that I removed all color and string resources from your XML so I could work with it. For at start remove the framlayout around your GridView and make your layouts a little bit more simple and not so nested

Comment: Yeah I added them back in, everything is the same except for the gridview, the items on it aren't showing up but I can click on them. https://hastebin.com/ucahuxucuj.xml

Answer (score 0):

Add sizes like this in Your ProgressBar:

```
android:maxHeight="20dp"
android:maxWidth="20dp"
android:minHeight="20dp"
android:minWidth="20dp"
```

Comment: Nope that doesn't do it.